# Prove that the subnormal series $GL_2(\mathbb{R})>N>\{I\}$ cannot be refined to produce a composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Prove that the subnormal series $GL_2(\mathbb{R})>N>\{I\}$ **cannot** be refined to produce a composition series. (Where $N$ is a normal subgroup in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$). Hence show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ does not have a composition series.

I have thought about going down the lines of a proof by contradiction so we would suppose that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})>N>\{I\}$ *can* be refined to produce a composition series. So this would mean we could make a refinement such that $$GL_2(\mathbb{R})>H>N>\{I\}$$ or $$GL_2(\mathbb{R})>N>H>\{I\}$$ give us a composition series. But I do not know where to go from here, could anyone help?

Comment: I am a bit lost. If we make the refinement ${I}\lhd K\lhd Z\lhd GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ then why isn't this now a composition series?

Comment: NOw I see the "refine to a **composition series** condition. Deleting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the cyclic group

$$N:=\left\langle\;\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\;\right\rangle\,\lhd GL(2,\Bbb R)$$

If $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ had a composition series then the subnormal series $\;I\lhd N\lhd GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ could be refined to a comp. series. But this is impossible since $\;N\cong\Bbb Z\;$ and an abelian group has a composition series iff it is finite.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}$ and why is $N$ isomorphic to it?

Comment: @harry55 $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is the rather well known additive group of the integers, the unique (up to isomorphism) infinite cyclic group. The fact that $\;N\cong\Bbb Z\;$ follows from the fact that the generator of $\;N\;$ has infinite order, as you can easily check...

Comment: Also I am asked to show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})>N>\{I\}$ cannot be refined to produce a composition series and _then_ from this show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ does not have a composition series. I cant see how you've shown that exactly?

Comment: And what about when N = $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &0\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @harry55 To ask this question you **must** already know quite a deal of basic group theory. Your questions make me wonder whether this is actually the case. Can't you really see that $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\ge N\ge I\;$ ?? And the explanation I gave in my question doesn't clearly shows the impossibility to build a composition series of the general linear group? I've no idea what you meant to ask in your last comment...

Comment: Sorry, I have dyslexia and find it difficult to get across exactly what I want to say.. I had confusion with $\mathbb{Z}$ because I had a vague memory of the $Z$ you used to define something in your previous deleted comment and thought you may be referring to that. I understand that $N$ has infinite order and that an abelian group has a composition series iff it is finite. However how have you used this fact to deduce that $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ does not have a composition series? As $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ is not abelian.

Comment: @harry55  I showed above a subnormal series $\;1\lhd N\lhd GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ . If this last group had a comp. series, then this series could be refined to obtain one. But $\;N\cong\Bbb Z\;$ is infinite abelian...

Comment: What if we had a different $N$? Is any possible $N$ of $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ always going to be abelian?

Comment: @harry55 No, of course not any subgroup is abelian. It is just that we took an example of subgroup which gives easily a proof. Had we chosen another noraml subgroup also there wouldn't be possible to construct a composition series.

Comment: You have used an example for $N$ but this would not suffice to prove in general that $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ does not have a composition series. So to prove in general can we say that for any $M$ where $M$ is a normal subgroup of $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\;$ such that $\;GL(2,\Bbb R)\; > M > I$ is a subnormal series , then this $M$ has to have the property that it is infinite abelian by construction of the subnormal series? And thus for any $M$ we would fail to refine to a composition series?

Comment: @harry55 Yes, it suffices because **any** subnormal series can be refined to a composition series...if one of these exists.